# Auto Mapper conditional mapper not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Trying to map a list of objects based on a condition.

> Keep getting "Cannot convert lambda expression to type IValueResolver"

Entity1.Contacts and Entity2.Users have mappings to ContactDetails. I cant see why this won't work

```
public class MyDTO{
  public List<ContactDetails> Contacts {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntity{
  public List<Entity1> Entities1 {get; set;}
  public List<Entity2> Entities2 {get; set;}
  public string Status {get; set;}
}

public MyMapping(){
   CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status == "TRUE"
                 ? src.Entities1.SelectMany(e1 => e1.Contacts)
                 : src.Entities2.SelectMany(e2 => e2.Users)));
}
```

Comment: Wrap the expression in ( )

Comment: Try implementing a value resolver https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Comment: @abdusco is it better to use a resolver or a standard method?

Comment: There's no "better" method. They're the same, it's just that one is more verbose.

Comment: You can have DI in a resolver.